# How to install extension in firefox automatically?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, firefox

I have the need to be able to install an extension that I made myself for Firefox in Ubuntu, but without a graphic terminal.  I need to be able to install the extension without the need for user interaction.

I want to do this because I am working with Docker and I do not have a graphical interface to be able to interact with my Ubuntu-based container. And therefore I cannot use beyond commands to interact with Ubuntu in my Docker container.

I'm trying to use the [Firefox command:](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Mozilla/Opciones_de_linea_de_Comandos)

> firefox -install-global-extension /path/to/extension

But it also requires user interaction so that it can accept the installation of the extension.

I found [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73474/how-to-install-firefox-addon-from-command-line-in-scripts) but I do not understand how to make the installation automatic, because loading the `.xpi` file to the folder with the extensions does not install in Firefox.

Comment: Can you add your image's `Dockerfile` to the question?  Running Firefox from inside a container can be rather tricky, and you won't have access to the running user's preferences or settings; is there a specific reason you're trying to use Docker here?

Comment: Do you use `policies.json`? You can set up `ExtensionSettings` there.

Comment: friend because I am working with multiple connections and the project requires me to use dockers.

Comment: M1K1O you could explain better about this file please ?